# How to store an array in a dictionary using python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I am currently attempting to modify a series of programs by utilizing dictionaries as opposed to arrays. I have columns of raw information in a file, which is then read into an ASCII csv file. I need to convert this file into a dictionary, so that it can be fed into another program.

I used a numpy.genfromtxt to pull out the information i need from the csv file, following this format:

```
a,b,c,d = np.genfromtxt("file",delimiter = ',', unpack = true)
```

this step works completely fine.

I then attempt to build a dictionary:

```
ouputDict = dict([a,a],[b,b],[c,c],[d,d])
```

As i understand it, this should make the **key "a"** in the dictionary a correspond to the **array "a"**.

thus if:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
```

then:

```
outputDict[a][0] = 1
```

However, when i attempt to create this dictionary i receive the following error:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Why can't I construct an array in this fashion and what is the workaround, if any? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: trying to build a dict that maps an array to the same array makes very little sense. I think you may have to rethink what inputs the other program requires. It seems that a list of arrays may make more sense.

Comment: i understand that you can't map an array to itself, and i apologize for any confusion. i was trying to make the keys have the same name as the arrays for convenience's sake

Comment: Did you try:  `{'a':a, 'b':b,...}`, or `dict(a=a, b=b,...)`?  `dict([('a', a), ('b', b)])` should also work.

Comment: I agree with what cel said,  trying to implement dictionary (which is not necessary) where the problem can be solved with an array is not a good way to code.

Comment: The problem is right now it's trying to set a numpy array as a key at some point and this won't work because python doesn't allow mutable objects as a key in a dict. That's where the unhashable exception is coming from

Comment: unfortunately i do not really have a choice in the usage of dictionaries. my original code did utilize a list of arrays. I am being required externally to rework these inputs. also thanks hpjaul, that did fix it. details... every time

Comment: also, thanks to Tgsmith for explaining where the unhashable is comnig from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from my comment:

Correct dictionary formats:

```
{'a':a, 'b':b,...}, or 
dict(a=a, b=b,...)
dict([('a', a), ('b', b),...])
```

The goal is to make the strings 'a','b',etc the keys, not the variable values.

Comment: Feel like a rookie, spent like an hour staring at dictionary documentation... thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can do this even with using collections

Declare your dictionary as:

`Dictionary = {};  // {} makes it a key, value pair dictionary`

add your value for which you want an array as a key by declaring

`Dictionary[a] = [1,2,3,4];    // [] makes it an array`

So now your dictionary will look like

`{a: [1,2,3,4]}`

Which means for key a, you have an array and you can insert data in that which you can access like dictionary[a][0] which will give the value 1 and so on. :)

Btw.. If you look into examples of a dictionary, array and key value pairs, nested dictionary, your concept will get clearer.

Comment: Oh ya i get it now, well I just started explaining the basic format.. lol.. old habits

Comment: This was really helpful, I hadn't been exposed to storing arrays in dictionaries before! You've solved my problem, thank you for posting @AmanChawla